# iPhone app Question related to AppStore

Tags: iphone, app-store

Here me having one question regarding iPhone app development for my existing website.

my website is for learning a language which has multiple choice questions so the user can practise using with that.The paid user can access all levels of the questions to practise.so the free access is a limited one.

So now, I want to have 5 paid app for different levels of questions and 1 app for free.

Now what i want to know is if a user who has already having paid access to WEBSITE , i want to offer them this iphone apps for free. but i am not sure how to go with the implementation of this.

Kindly help me out with your Views and Thanks A LOT

**

**UPDATE : 1**

**
Also which would be the correct way to store all my questions nearly 2000 questions  ( to have a database or to fetch those questions from webserver using web services )

Comment: My answer has been updated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks like the best solution is to cross-check the credentials and subscription levels of the users and offer/not offer paid-for features of the app.

So basically, you should have in-app purchases for your app based on the subscription level of a user. For example, if the user already has a paid account in the website, the iPhone app would have all the features unlocked. Else, let the user pay from within the app and you could then (possibly) have paid features enabled in the website.

Answer to Update 1: 
It depends.

1. If you are questions are media-bound and contain a lot of videos/images/audio then it *probably* is a good idea to stream them, warning the user before-hand the data charges he is going to incur.
2. If your questions are plain text, they would not be heavy. 2000 questions in plain-text can be wrapped up within the app.